# Code running despite no input being given (python)

Tags: python-3.x

When the user enters nothing, it is supposed to loop back and ask the question again. It performs correctly with every other type of input.

Here is the code:

```
string = ""

def str_analysis(string):

    while True:
        if string.isdigit():
            if int(string) > 99:
                print(str(string)+ " is a pretty big number!")
                break
            else:
                print(str(string)+ " is a smaller number than expected")
                break
        elif string.isalpha():
            print(string + " is an alphabetical character")
            break
        elif string == "":
            print("")
        else:
            print(string + " is a surprise! It's neither all alpha nor all digit characters!")
            break

print(str_analysis(input("Enter word or integer: ")))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things in your code that make no sense.

1:

> print(str_analysis(input("Enter word or integer: ")))

You are trying to print the output of a function that has no return value

2:
It cant loop back and ask the question again, because the input is not taken inside of the function.

3:
If the string is empty you dont break the code but constantly print newlines.

Here is some code wich I think should do what you wanted:

```
def str_analasys():
    while True:
        string = input("Enter word or integer: ")
        if string == '':
            continue

        elif string.isdigit():
            if int(string) > 99:
                print(str(string)+ " is a pretty big number!")
            else:
                print(str(string)+ " is a smaller number than expected")
        elif string.isalpha():
            print(string + " is an alphabetical character")
        else:
            print(string + " is a surprise! It's neither all alpha nor all digit characters!")

        break
str_analasys()
```

Answer (score 0):

This because when `string` is empty you are just printing an empty `""`

```
elif string == "":
    print("")
    # break it here or take input again
    # break or string = input()
```